# Scala traits and structural types: can a trait extend a structural type and then call super?

Tags: scala

I'd like to have a trait that can a) be mixed into any class with a particular method, and b) can call super.  Something like this:

```
  // A and B are from a library that I don't control.  No changes allowed here.
  class A {
    def stuff = "a stuff"
  }
  class B {
    def stuff = "b stuff"
  }

  // My code starts here

  type HasStuffMethod = {
    def stuff: String
  }

  // Note that this doesn't compile - gets:
  //   class type required but AnyRef{def stuff: String} found
  trait ImplementsStuff extends HasStuffMethod {
    override def stuff = "trait + " + super.stuff
  }

  val a = new A with ImplementsStuff
  assert(a.stuff == "trait + a stuff")

  val b = new B with ImplementsStuff
  assert(b.stuff == "trait + b stuff")
```

Is there any way to do this?

Note that I don't control A and B; they're coming from another library that I can't modify.

[Edit - added after seeing answers]

Is there a way to call the original method in something like this?

```
  trait ImplementsStuff {
    this: HasStuffMethod =>
    abstract override def stuff = "foo" + "how do I call the original method here?"
  }
```

This isn't useful, since when you mix it into something it gives:

> error: overriding method stuff in class A of type => java.lang.String;
>   method stuff in trait ImplementsStuff of type => java.lang.String
>   cannot override a concrete member without a third member that's
>   overridden by both (this rule is designed to prevent ``accidental
>   overrides'')

But it's no accident; yes, I really do want you to step all over that existing method.  And then let me call it, too.

Comment: Here `HasStuffMethod` is not a type class. It's a type alias to a structural type.

Comment: Right - a typeclass pattern is something else. And it's irrelevant to this question whether `HasStuffMethod` is a structural or a nominal type (i.e. a regular trait).

Comment: I've added a proposed edit to your question. I hope it clarifies what you're trying to do. If I've misinterpreted you can erase it. If it's correct, you can use it to rephrase your question. In that case, please also edit the reference to "typeclass" in the question's title.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella, I think I see where you're going, but I think the proposed edit doesn't really make it any clearer.  It's always wrong to repeat code, so there's a big chunk of the proposed edit that has to go away, and I don't think what's left is really different than the original.  Definitely the reference to typeclass in my original is just wrong and I'll fix it.  (Upvoted your comment)

Comment: I think I got what you were asking, but it seemed to me that Daniel C.Sobral and paradigmatic didn't. Since they are both much more expert in scala than I am, I thought that maybe rephrasing your question could get you a better answer than mine. However, you're probably right that my proposed edit wasn't really an improvement.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of two options:

option 1, using a self type annotation and calling `stuff` from a new method (that I imaginatively called `callStuff`) instead of overriding it.

```
  trait ImplementsStuff  {
    this: HasStuffMethod =>
    def callStuff = "trait + " + this.stuff
  }

  val a = new A with ImplementsStuff
  assert(a.callStuff == "trait + a stuff")

  val b = new B with ImplementsStuff
  assert(b.callStuff == "trait + b stuff")
```

option 2 (since you say you don't control A and B) is the dear old decorator pattern.

```
  trait HasStuff { def stuff: String }

  class DecorateStuff(decorated: HasStuffMethod) extends HasStuff {
    def stuff = "trait + " + decorated.stuff
  }
  val decA = new DecorateStuff(new A)
  assert(decA.stuff == "trait + a stuff")

  val decB = new DecorateStuff(new B)
  assert(decB.stuff == "trait + b stuff")
```

Comment: Both interesting, but neither solves the problem.  The first one fails because there's no way to tell all the callers that they have to call a new method (and so the asserts definitely fail).  The second returns a different type, so it's a useful technique but it doesn't really help here - what do you you do when you need to pass the new thing to other code that's expecting an A, not a DecorateStuff?

Comment: @JamesMoore You are right, both methods assume that you/your team control the caller code. If that's not the case and your expectations are to change their stuff method's behavior but still have A and B, this looks like Aspect Oriented Programming. You can look at AspectJ. [This article by Jonas Boner may help you](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/real-world-scala-managing-cros)

Comment: It's just that the existing system seems _soooo_ close to what I'd like.  In your first example, if you could change callStuff to plain stuff, and then have a way to reference the method being overridden, you'd have it.  (Added that to my question)

Answer (score 4):

You need an `abstract override` in such a case.

Comment: How do you define the trait?  (Added a note that the line "trait ImplementsStuff extends HasStuffMethod" doesn't compile.)

Comment: @JamesMoore Just `abstract override def ...`. But I just noticed you have it exteding a `type` -- `type` is just an alias, and your alias is a structural type: that won't work. Make it extend an `abstract class` instead, or a `trait`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to extend a refined type in Scala (I'm not sure this could be pulled off safely, but it would be interesting to explore).

I have a solution that's more verbose, but gets you closer to your goal.

```
trait HasStuff {
  def theirStuff: String
}

trait ImplementsStuff extends HasStuff {
  def stuff = "trait + " + theirStuff
}
```

Notice that instead of a refined type I have a trait, and extend it in the implementation. I need to add super accessors manually, I do that by delegation. `HasStuff` defines them, and I implement them at the mixin site:

```
val a = new A with ImplementsStuff {
  def theirStuff = super[A].stuff

  override def stuff = super[ImplementsStuff].stuff
}

val b = new B with ImplementsStuff {
  def theirStuff = super[B].stuff

  override def stuff = super[ImplementsStuff].stuff
}
```

At the mixin site I need to implement the super accessor (`theirStuff`) to forward to the right inherited method. I also need to override `stuff` at this level, since `ImplementsStuff` does not inherit a `stuff` method, therefore it can't `override` it.

Calling `stuff` on `a` and `b` shows it has been overridden:

```
$ a.stuff
res0: java.lang.String = trait + a stuff

$ b.stuff
res1: java.lang.String = trait + b stuff
```